# Bind this argument to named argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

In the case I have a code structure as follows :

```
 Thing.prototype = {

    doSomething: function() {
      $(selector).click(this.handleClick.bind(null, this));
    },

    handleClick: function(self, event) {
      console.log(this); //Window
      console.log(self); //Thing
    }

 }
```

How could one bind the Thing `this` context to the `self` argument and still keep the behavior of the `this` object as if no arguments were bound using the `bind` method?

*Note* : I know I can bind `this` and use `e.originalEvent.target` to get the behaviour I want but I'm just curious if there is another way

I hope I'm getting through with what I want to achieve, leave a comment if something is ambiguous.

Comment: No I want to use the handler's original `this` (the clicked element) but pass the Thing `this` to the self variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could one bind the Thing this context to the self argument and still keep the behavior of the this object as if no arguments were bound using the bind method?

You wouldn't use `bind` for that, because you want `this` to be dynamic. Instead:

```
doSomething: function() {
  var self = this;
  $(selector).click(function(e) {
      return self.handleClick.call(this, self, e);
  });
},
```

During `handleClick`, `this` would refer to the element that was clicked, the first argument would be the `Thing` instance, and the second would be the event:

```
handleClick: function(self, event) {
  console.log(this);  // The clicked element
  console.log(self);  // The Thing
  console.log(event); // The event
}
```

Comment: That's great, I'm still trying to get around the `bind` behaviour. A thorough explanation of this behaviour from a doc page would be welcome, if anything is available :)

Comment: @SpyrosMandekis [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is some nice documentation on .bind() with examples, but T.J. Crowder's link below to the spec should be even more precise, albeit dry.

Comment: @SpyrosMandekis: There's [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5). :-) Fundamentally, if you want `this` to be determined when the function is *called*, `bind` isn't the right tool, because it fixes what `this` will be in advance.